# In VS Code on Linux, how do I disable copy on selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.32 on Ubuntu, which I access as a remote client app through SSH on Windows.

Whenever I select text using the mouse or the clipboard, it is automatically copied in the clipboard. The only plugins I have are Prettier and ESLint.

How can I disable that behavior?

Comment: I assume you are not talking about just in the terminal?  There is "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": false for that.

Comment: No, it's in the editor but thanks

Comment: The same things is happening to me, only on ssh host, and the solutions bellow didn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Settings: Editor: Selection Clipboard - uncheck

Comment: This also appears to disable middle-click paste unfortunately

Comment: Is there a way to enable auto-copy in current vscode? Settings: Editor: Selection Clipboard is checked, but still selection isn't copied to clipboard (I wish it were)

Comment: There is also Copy on Select: Copy on Mouse Selection

Answer (score 3):

Go to `File > Preferences > Settings` and search for "Right Click Behaviour".
Change the option of `Terminal > Integrated: Right Click Behaviour` from `copyPaste` to 'default`.

Comment: The terminal setting has moved and is now under the path `Features > Terminal > Integrated: Right Click Behaviour`

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me while using VNC Viewer - The solution was disabling "Send primary selection to viewers" in VNC config window.

Answer (score 2):

In the Files/Preferences/Settings search for "Editor: Copy With Syntax Highlighting" and disable it. That worked in my case with VS Code 1.42

Comment: Settings: Text Editor: Selection Clipboard - uncheck is the correct answer for OP's question.